# Rn Lottie: .then() function after animation is complete

Tags: javascript, react-native, lottie

I have the following lottie animation in my RN project:

```
<Animation
            ref={animation => {
              this.animation = animation;
            }}
            style={{
              width: 40,
              height: 40
            }}
            loop={true}
            source={favorite}
            progress={0}
             />
```

I have the animation wrapped inside a `<touchableOpacity/>`
is it possible to do something like this in lottie:

```
 onPress={() => {

                this.animation.play().then(
                 // do something
    )

}
```

I want to wait for the animation to finish playing before I go on to do something else. is this possible?

Comment: Based on the current properties it provides, i think you may need to monitor the `progress` prop and call the function once it is set to `1`